# Powershell .csv foreach row add same value

Tags: powershell

I am exporting information about members of group from AD and I want to pass them a 'target' value in new column. 
I was able to find out how to create a new header, but not how to add values. It should be rather simple, because right now I just need to pass the same value for all users.

```
Import-Csv unformatted.csv | Select-Object *,"Target" | Export-csv Target.csv -NoTypeInformation

LogonName,Email,Target
abc,abc@a.com,
bcd,bcd@a.com,
cde,cde@a.com,
```

I want to see such result

```
LogonName,Email,Target
abc,abc@a.com,TARGET
bcd,bcd@a.com,TARGET
cde,cde@a.com,TARGET
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close indeed. Use [Calculated properties](https://workingsysadmin.com/calculated-properties-in-powershell/) like this -

```
Import-Csv unformatted.csv | Select-Object *,@{Name='Target';Expression={'TARGET'}} | Export-csv Target.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

**OR**

You can add property to the objects like this -

```
$csv = import-csv -path unformatted.csv -header LogonName,Email
foreach($item in $csv)
{
    Add-Member -Input $item -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Target -Value 'TARGET'
}
$csv | Select-Object LogonName, Email, Target | export-csv -path Target.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly, also the second solution will come in useful later on in more complicated examples, so double thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Import-Csv unformatted.csv | Select-Object *, @{name="Target"; expression={"TARGRET"}} | Export-csv Target.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: `expression={"TARGRET"}` "Targret, Margret!" [*grin*]